# "Silverware", "Tableware", and "Dishes"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, american-english

What are the common and current, American English general words encapsulating:

> **1. Knives, forks, and spoons.**

I know the words "**silverware**" as well as "**flatware**", but I don't know which one is more appropriate and precise here! On top of that, I don't know if these words sound normal in everyday conversation or not!

**Note:** also, "cutlery" as far as I'm concerned is a British / Canadian term which many Americans may even never have heard of.

> **2. Knives, forks, spoons,  +  plates, glasses, etc. used for meals.**

I know "**tableware**" which [as per Cambridge](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/tableware) is a formal word. While I need a word that people use in everyday speech at the table.

**Note:** as far as I know, "crockery" is a British / Canadian term which many Americans are not familiar with. Besides, it does not encompass "knives", "forks", and "spoons".

In addition to that, I am really interested to know how I can distinguish the word "**dishes**" from all of these?

Comment: When you say **dishes** do you mean *more than one dish/bowl (bowls)* or more general collective term for *plates / bowls / etc* (as in washing the dishes / dishwasher)

Comment: In this way I am refering to a package of things; perhaps: glasses, plates, forks and spoons etc.

Comment: Of interest at EL&U: *[Where is the word “cutlery” in common usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148490)*; *[Plastic silverware - What's that? (American English)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285284)*; and *[What's the difference between 'cutlery', 'silverware' and 'crockery'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/)*

Comment: Be aware that outside North America, some people will understand "flatware" to mean the china stuff - plates and so on (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/flatware).

Answer (score 13):

In my experience, silverware is the most common term for metal eating utensils (forks, knives, spoons), though flatware is also perfectly acceptable. I've also heard and used cutlery to describe this set of items, though in the U.S., cutlery can also refer to kitchen knives of all kinds.

Crockery is very common to refer to ceramic dish sets, also just referred to as "the dishes" or "dishware"; in my experience, the more formal version of this would be "fine china."

Tableware doesn't strike me as particularly formal, but there's also not very many situations where I'd be talking about the table settings as a whole, and not the individual parts--the glasses, the plates, the silverware, etc.

Comment: Aha, and @Katy do you confirm that "dishes" and "tableware" are interchangeable in AmE and both can be used in everyday speech in the same way?

Comment: No one talks about their flatware and tableware. That is a commercial term, what you see when you go shopping. They talk about silverware and dishes in everyday speech. What people say everyday and what you see in stores/shops/online are two different things.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is common or something local to me, but in my experience, flatware is typically used to distinguish stainless steel utensils (flatware) from silver utensils (_silver_ ware), but only when the distinction matters: eg. when setting up a formal dinner, one would specify whether to set the table with flatware or silverware.

Comment: @Lambie, I agree with asgallant, my wife will often ask for flatware at a restaurant, because she knows they do not have silverware. If we were at a restaurant with silverware, it would probably be set correctly to begin with!

Comment: @GlenYates, When I am at a restaurant, I ask for knives and forks. flatware is a shopping, commercial term. Silverware is not just for knives and  forks made of silver. You can ask for silverware even if it is steel rather than silver.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks "plates" when I hear "flatware"?  A plate is easily as "flat" as most cutlery at least the way I think of flatness.

Comment: @asgallant I've heard similar things, but I think that usage is on its way out. Fine utensils (true "silverware") are, in my experience, referred to as simply "silver" if a single term is used at all. Silverware has been a very everyday term for common utensils in my ~30 years of life in the U.S., and never once have I seen any confusion over regular flatware and fine silver utensils. I also hear *flatware* used interchangeably with, but much less often than *silverware*. Relatively few people even *have* fine utensils of any material these days-- it's a distinction with diminishing relevance.

Comment: Well @Upper_Case do you confirm that silverware and flatware can be used interchangeably? Also, do you agree that these two terms can be used for any color of utensils (silver/gold etc.)?

Comment: @A-friend That's the usage I've encountered all my life, without any exceptions that I can recall. Modern common usage doesn't distinguish between the color of the utensil or the materials from which the utensils are made when choosing between these words, and I've never heard *flatware* or *silverware* used in a situation where the other would be inappropriate for the speaker's meaning. That said, I've found *flatware* to be a less common term-- but that could easily be regional, or based on some other non-general distinction.

Comment: Thank you @Upper_Case, just I wonder if in your part of the country (which I don't know where it is in the US,) the words (cutlery/silverware/flatware) and (crockery/tableware) are somehow commercial or uncommon in everyday conversations.

Comment: @A-friend Search on Amazon for Kitchen Drawer Organizer and see what types of terms are used to describe the utensils that go into it.  Some use the term flatware, some silverware, some cutlery.  They all seem to refer to the storage of utensils for everyday use. Based on this, I would say they are used interchangeably.

Comment: @A-friend I live in the upper-Midwest, and in my experience it is *cutlery*, *flatware*, and *silverware* in terms of commonness of usage from least common to most (with *silverware* being far and away the most common). All three terms would likely be recognized by most adults. Neither *crockery* nor *tableware* is really a commercial term, but they are uncommon in everyday English. I hear (and use) *crockery* when describing my *cookware* but never anything I use to serve (even when *crock* would be appropriate). *Tableware* is simply not a term I use or see used, though I understand it fine.

Comment: So silverware is a common (apparently the most common term,) but what about the alternative for "tableware" @Upper_Case?

Comment: "fine china" is a specific material, it's not a formal word for "dishes". Though at a formal dinner the plates may indeed be fine china.

Comment: @A-friend It's a word that most people in the U.S. will immediately understand, at least vaguely, but I hear it very, very rarely and I'm not sure if I've ever actually used it myself. It might fit well in a specific setting (so if you hear people around you using it, you may want to use it too), but it's uncommon enough that I would suggest using any of *silverware*, *flatware*, or *cutlery* instead.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding "the dishes":

**A dish**, in my area of the USA is more often called "a *plate*". It is a flat, usually round thing made from plastic, glass, or ceramic that you put non-liquid food on and eat from.

However, **the dishes** can either mean a collection of plates, (especially as compared to *bowls*, as in "put the dishes here and the bowls there"), but most often means all the things that are used for eating and drinking in the phrase, "*do the dishes*". To *do the dishes* means to clean all the plates, bowls, cups, glasses, forks, knives, spoons, pots, and pans or rinse them and put them in the automatic dishwasher to be cleaned. I believe in British English this is often called "washing up".

For example, in the song about Cinderella from the Disney animated movie *Cinderella*, they sing about her doing, "the dishes and the mopping/they always keep her hopping". In that case, *the dishes* means **all** the tableware as I described in at the end of the previous paragraph.

"Silverware" and "cutlery" are commonly used in my area of the USA to mean forks, knives, and spoon that are used at the table for eating. "Flatware" means the same thing (in my experience) but is rarely used in a normal household. "Tableware" is most often used in stores, catalogs, and websites that sell kitchen and dining implements to indicate all the things that are used to eat at the table as opposed to things used in the kitchen to cook food. "Flatware" is also used in the same contexts to mean the forks, knives, and spoons used at the table for eating, as opposed to any forks, knives, or spoons used for cooking, which are usually larger (and sharper, in the case of knives).

I rarely hear "cutlery" used in homes, but sometimes in restaurant the sets of silverware wrapped up in napkins that are placed at the tables are called "cutlery" or "cutlery sets" by staff or customers.

To summarize my answers to your two questions:

1. “Silverware”
2. There is no word I use for all of those things that doesn’t also include things that don’t usually go on the table. But if you include the pots and pans and so on that are in the kitchen, then it’s “the dishes”. How do you get everything off the table to “do the dishes”? You “clear the table”. When getting ready for a meal, you “set the table”. What do you set the table with? “Silverware, plates (and/or bowls), and glasses”. There is no one word I know of that is used commonly to mean all the things that go on the table.

Comment: There's also "plasticware", meaning utensils made of plastic, as commonly used with takeout food or on picnics.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure if I've heard it, but I'm not surprised if that is used. Around me that's usually called "disposable" or just "plastic", as in "pass me one of those plastic forks".

Comment: Isn't a dish also a single food? "I'm bringing eggplant casserole as my potluck dish."

Comment: Thank you @Todd Wilcox, but what do you use in everyday speech instead of (cutlery/utensils/flatware/silverware) and (crockery/tableware)?

Comment: @A-friend My everyday words are in the answer but here they are again. “Silverware”: forks, knives, spoons. “Plates”: things you eat off of that aren’t bowls. “The dishes”: all the things used for cooking and/or eating and/or drinking. I don’t know what “crockery” means so I don’t have a word for that. I don’t normally say any word that means the same thing as “tableware”. I might say “set the table with silverware, plates, and glasses”, so I don’t use just one word for all the tableware.

Comment: @A-friend I forgot the word ***utensils***!! That is definitely used by me and many others in the US, but it is a bit more complicated. “Plastic utensils” means plastic forks, knives and spoons. But “the utensil drawer” in the kitchen usually has none of those, instead it has the garlic press, can opener, ice cream scoop, cheese grater, whisks, tongs, and other kitchen implements that are used in food preparation.

Comment: Hm, to me a bowl is a *dish* no less than a plate is, though I'm aware of the etymology (*disc*).